# How can I check warranty state of my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, warranty

I’m from Maldives and I am buying an iPhone 6 plus from a shop in Male. They say that there is a 1 year Apple warranty but they aren’t providing me with any slips of the warranty.

How can I verify whether my iPhone is covered by warranty?

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides an online tool to check service and support coverage using your device's serial number.  You can find the serial number on your iPhone by tapping *Settings > General > About*.

[SelfSolve.apple.com](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do) allows you to enter an Apple serial number and then see what warranty options are available.
The device does not need to be registered in order to be checked.

See below for an example of a MacBook Air that is still covered under AppleCare.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You could check it on [Apple Support](https://supportprofile.apple.com).

If your iPhone is registered it will appear there and you will be able to check your warranty status. If is not registered, you must do it there.

Answer (score 0):

Selfsolve.apple.com is definitely the right place to check warranty coverage. You can also call Apple with the serial number (phone number below).

Before you buy, is it used? If so, make sure it is removed from the previous owner's Apple ID so you aren't locked out! More tips on buying used iPhones [here](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/03/tips-buy-used-iphone.html).

I'd also recommend going to supportprofile.apple.com afterwards where you can edit registration information for the device if it's not currently registered. If it's not under warranty, it's always worth calling in to see if there is a recall or replacement program for the issue you're experiencing. AppleCare is 1-800-275-2273.